# Select Install Drive (wix)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've developed a Wix control that lets me select from various drives that are installed on my machine.  I've pasted the code in below.

I have two questions:
1) How do I pop up a dialog box shows my drive selection?
2) How do I use the drive selection to determine where to install my app?  Note: if its on the C Drive, I want it installed to program files, else Drive:\Company\Product.

Any help would be appreciated.  I apologize if this was covered elsewhere online.  I couldn't find a clear cut solution online.

My control code is as follows:

```
    <Control Id="myVolumeSelectCombo" Type="VolumeSelectCombo" Property="TARGETDIR2" Fixed="yes" Remote="yes" X="10" Y="100" Width="100" Height="17">
      <Publish Property="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[TARGETDIR2]Company\Product\" Order="1"><![CDATA[TARGETDIR2 = "C:\"]]></Publish>
      <Publish Property ="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[TARGETDIR2]Company\Product\" Order="2"><![CDATA[TARGETDIR2 <> "C:\"]]></Publish>
      <Publish Event="SetTargetPath" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" Order="3"></Publish>
    </Control>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Page 216 of this book explains everything:

[https://www.amazon.com/WiX-3-6-Developers-Windows-Installer/dp/1782160426/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1472845444&sr=8-5&keywords=wix](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782160426)